# I wanna upgrade my pc and want to know if the procesor is compatible

Tags: processor, intel, upgrade

I'm upgrading my desktop computer, it's a computer for development, I don't understand much about hardware though. Could somebody please tell me if the processor Intel Bx80684I99900K Intel Core I9-9900K is compatible with my PC? I'll leave the link and my pc settings bellow for clarity. Thanks in advance!

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i99900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html

[image: CPU settings]
[image: Mainboard settings]

Chers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [No.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1151#LGA_1151_revision_2)

The 1151 socket has two versions. Your i3-7100 is a Kaby Lake generation CPU that uses the original 1151 socket version.

The i9-9900K and all other Coffee Lake generation CPUs use a new version of the 1151 socket that is not compatible. This version is often referred to as "1151-2".

The "1151" in the socket name is the number of pins the socket has, and unfortunately that naming scheme can lead to confusion when two completely different sockets use the same number of pins. Things get even more confusing because these two 1151 sockets use the same physical CPU dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Romen!

I ended up upgrading to an i7 6700K, it's reaching 100 ºC sometimes, though. I don't know it's due to have kept the same cooler i had for the other processor i had before, o  i haven't applyed enough thermical paste...

Comment: I would guess that the thermal paste being applied incorrectly is one likely cause for really high temps. The CPU is also a lot higher power in the first place so it needs a better cooler than an i3 does.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not

Intel cpu's can only upgrade one generation on the same motherboard, and the 7th generation is already the "upgrade" of the 6th generation. They are similar socket though and there are motherboards that allow 6th to 9th gen upgrade, but those are rare.